# Check if any dates within a range fall within a specified month

Tags: c#, datetime

I am at a bit of a loss as to the best approach.  Let's say I have the following:

```
//Get the first and last day of the month -- ex February
int month = DateTime.ParseExact("February", "MMMM", new CultureInfo("en-US")).Month;
var now = DateTime.Now;

var firstOfMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, month, 1);
var lastOfMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, month));

var coverageStartDate = new DateTime(now.Year, 1, 1);
var coverageEndDate = new DateTime(now.Year, 2, 15);
```

I am trying to create a check to see if the date range of coverageStartDate and coverageEndDate falls in the month of February.  Keep in mind that the values could also look like:

```
var coverageStartDate = new DateTime(now.Year, 2, 3);
var coverageEndDate = new DateTime(now.Year, 2, 10);
```

As long as there is a single date in the coverage start / end date range falls in the month of February, I would want to return true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `DateTime` you can use >=, <=, etc.

Adopting your code, I would do something like this:

```
var firstOfMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, month, 1, 0, 0, 0);
var lastOfMonth = new DateTime(now.Year, month, DateTime.DaysInMonth(now.Year, month), 23, 59, 59);

var coverageStartDate = new DateTime(now.Year, 1, 1);
var coverageEndDate = new DateTime(now.Year, 2, 15);

if(coverageStartDate <= lastOfMonth && coverageEndDate >= firstOfMonth)
{
  // Do something
}
```

This code does not requires that years have to be the same, so the coverage time can span multiple years.